# Google Bucket Images crashes Sometimes without any reason

Tags: html, angularjs, google-cloud-storage

i was tried to gave the images Dynamically for my html page, so i used google image bucket and got the URL. And then i saved that URL into my Database. And retrieve that images one by one. I got the output too but the problem here is my output's are not consistent. After 10 or 15 minutes its getting crashed and showing a error in my console also. So what will be the problem ?

And the Error was :
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()

Comment: What does the URL to download the images look like? Are the images publicly available? Are you downloading them with a web browser or as an authorized user in a client library?

Comment: That was my fault Brandon, Instead of getting the Public link URL i was used that direct link that's why it was crashed ! Now i just fixed that,